# Furnace Water Drainage from inducer motor

Tags: furnace

My furnace(an amana) seems to be stopping due to too much water in the inducer motor.  If I pull the yellow plug from the motor housing, a good amount of water comes out and then the unit will work again.

After a lot of troubleshooting I noticed something.  There are two drains.  One is up top left near the exhaust exit and the other is at the bottom right.  They drain into a reservoir.  I made it so I could see each drain emptying when it was running.  The one on the bottom right does not drain until the unit is turned off/stopped! This is telling me that it is not clogged(which is what I thought was my problem for some time).

Which seems like a problem.  If the until has to run for too long, then the water fills up and then the inducer motor stops.

Does this seem like it is working right?  Or should it drain the entire time?

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: Can you include a photo of the drain plumbing?  Sounds like you don't have a trap, or a improperly plumbed trap.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your trap may not have enough height to keep air from being pulled in. I have to make traps that were close to 5" to prevent the pressure from pulling the water out of the trap. Yes they do get dirty and need to be cleaned, but if the trap is holding water it will drain while running, if the trap is not deep enough air is pulled through the trap and water will build up until it is deep enough in the pan or shuts down and gravity pulls it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have an American Standard 90+ furnace like yours. The drains run into a trap mechanism. This trap mechanism gets plugged up occasionally with dirt and gunk and I have to remove the line or lines going into it and flush it out with water under pressure. Once cleaned out I put the hoses back on and the furnace works again. I now clean it out once a year in the summer.

Comment: I added an update.  It does not appear to be clogged.  The water does drain after the unit turns off just fine.  Just not while it is running.

Comment: @Womack -- in that case, you have a malfunctioning or incorrectly built trap.